# Совместимость IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Добрый день!
Есть документ с метой:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

В Internet Explorer 8 он грузится со следующими параметрами:
Режим обозревателя: IE8, Режим документов: стандартный IE8.
И отображается некорректно, переключаю режим документов в IE7, потом возвращаю в IE8, документ перезагружается и отображается корректно.

Есть идеи как заставить его отображаться корректно с первого раза без передергивания режима документа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE считает нужным показывать страницы в интранете в режиме эмуляции IE7.

Переключение вручную помогает из-за того, что когда открыты инструменты разработчика, выбранное в них значение имеет приоритет над всеми правилами.

[Вероятно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887546/4928642), поможет честная отправка http-заголовка вместо прописывания meta-тега на странице.

А вообще, погугли *X-UA-Compatible intranet*.

Comment: при открытии dev tools показывается тот режим, который был "угадан" IE при загрузке страницы. Т.е. если там написано IE8, то это действительно IE8. И прописывание конкретной версии (IE=8), в  отличие от просто edge, пробивает настройку Display intranet sites in Compatibility View. Так что у топикастера явно что-то другое.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю власти над самим документом у вас нет, иначе было бы логичено просто убрать эту мету. В остальном это мета конкретно указывает IE что режим страницы "оптимизирован" под IE8 так что логично, что именно в этом режиме оно и отображается. Ответ по всей видимости "никак". Либо может где-то есть настройка, о которой я не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Если закомментить мету, страница отображается в формате IE7 (Стандартный), что приводит  к некорректному отображению.